# Inexplicable behavior when using vlen with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am using h5py to build a dataset. Since I want to store arrays with different #of rows dimension, I use the h5py special_type vlen. However, I experience behavior I can't explain, maybe you can me help in understanding what is happening:

```
>>>> import h5py
>>>> import numpy as np
>>>> fp = h5py.File(datasource_fname, mode='w') 
>>>> dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('float32'))
>>>> train_targets = fp.create_dataset('target_sequence', shape=(9549, 5,), dtype=dt)
>>>> test
Out[130]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
>>>> train_targets[0] = test
>>>> train_targets[0]
Out[138]: 
array([ array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.], dtype=float32),
        array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

I do expect the `train_targets[0]` to be of this shape, however I can't recognize the rows in my array. They seem to be totally jumbled about, however it is consistent. By which I mean that every time I try the above code, `train_targets[0]` looks the same.

To clarify: the first element in my `train_targets`, in this case `test`, has shape `(5,11)`, however the second element might be of shape `(5,38)` which is why I use vlen.

Thank you for your help

Mat

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
train_targets[0] = test
```

has stored your `(11,5)` array as an `F` ordered array in a row of `train_targets`.  According to the `(9549,5)` shape, that's a row of 5 elements.  And since it is `vlen`, each element is a 1d array of length 11.

That's what you get back in `train_targets[0]` - an array of 5 arrays, each shape `(11,)`, with values taken from `test` (order F).

So I think there are 2 issues - what a 2d shape means, and what vlen allows.

---

My version of `h5py` is pre v2.3, so I only get string vlen.  But I suspect your problem may be that `vlen` only works with 1d arrays, an extension, so to speak, of byte strings.

Does the `5` in `shape=(9549, 5,)` have anything to do with `5` in the `test.shape`?  I don't think it does, at least not as `numpy` and `h5py` see it.

When I make a file following the string vlen example:

```
>>> f = h5py.File('foo.hdf5')
>>> dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
>>> ds = f.create_dataset('VLDS', (100,100), dtype=dt)
```

and then do:

```
ds[0]='this one string'
```

and look at `ds[0]`, I get an object array with 100 elements, each being this string.  That is, I've set a whole row of `ds`.

```
ds[0,0]='another'
```

is the correct way to set just one element.

`vlen` is 'variable length', not 'variable shape'.  While the https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/TechNotes/VLTypes.html documentation is not entirely clear on this, I think you can store 1d arrays with shape `(11,)` and `(38,)` with `vlen`, but not 2d ones.

---

Actually, `train_targets` output is reproduced with:

```
In [54]: test1=np.empty((5,),dtype=object)
In [55]: for i in range(5):
    test1[i]=test.T.flatten()[i:i+11]
```

It's 11 values taken from the transpose (F order), but shifted for each sub array.

Comment: Thx for the explanation @hpaulj. The solution lies in that one needs to explicitly set each vector, not the whole matrix. 2d indeed does not work.