# Setting and reading dimscale in hdf5 files correctly in python

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to attach dimension scales to datasets I want to store in hdf5 files with python, but get an error when I try to print the attributes after setting them. The relevant code snippet reads as follows:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# create data and x-axis
my_data = np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 200))
x_axis  = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

h5f = h5.File('my_file.h5','w')
h5f.create_dataset( 'data_1', data=my_data )
h5f['data_1'].dims[0].label = 'm'
h5f['data_1'].dims.create_scale( h5f['x_axis'], 'x' )

# the following line is creating the problems
h5f['data_1'].dims[0].attach_scale( h5f['x_axis'] )

# this is where the crash happens but only if the above line is included
for ii in h5f['data_1'].attrs.items():
    print ii

h5f.close()
```

The command `print(h5.version.info)` prints the following output:

```
Summary of the h5py configuration
---------------------------------

h5py    2.2.1
HDF5    1.8.11
Python  2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
sys.platform    linux2
sys.maxsize     9223372036854775807
numpy   1.8.2
```

The error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HDF_write_dimScales.py", line 16
    for ii in h5f['data_1'].attrs.items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/base.py", line 347, in items
    return [(x, self.get(x)) for x in self]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/base.py", line 310, in get
    return self[name]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/attrs.py", line 55, in __getitem__
    rtdt = readtime_dtype(attr.dtype, [])
  File "h5a.pyx", line 318, in h5py.h5a.AttrID.dtype.__get__ (h5py/h5a.c:4285)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 337, in h5py.h5t.TypeID.py_dtype (h5py/h5t.c:3892)
TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeVlenID exists
```

Any ideas or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with some slight adjusts for me on `h5py 2.5.0`. The problem may be to do with when you call `create_scale`. With `h5py 2.5.0`, I get a `KeyError` for `h5f['x_axis']` in your `create_scale()` call. To get your example to work, I had to explicitly create the `x_axis` dataset first.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# create data and x-axis
my_data = np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 200))

# Use a context manager to ensure h5f is closed
with h5py.File('my_file.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset( 'data_1', data=my_data )

    # Create the x_axis dataset directly in the HDF5 file
    h5f['x_axis']  = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

    h5f['data_1'].dims[0].label = 'm'

    # Now we can create and attach the scale without problems
    h5f['data_1'].dims.create_scale( h5f['x_axis'], 'x' )
    h5f['data_1'].dims[0].attach_scale( h5f['x_axis'] )

    for ii in h5f['data_1'].attrs.items():
        print(ii)

# Output
#(u'DIMENSION_LABELS', array(['m', ''], dtype=object))
#(u'DIMENSION_LIST', array([array([<HDF5 object reference>], dtype=object),
#       array([], dtype=object)], dtype=object))
```

---

If you're still having problems, you may have to upgrade to `h5py 2.5.0`, which has better handling (although still not perfect) of VLEN types.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not solve my problem. I guess I will check the update possibilities of the server I am working on (where I have no superuser/root access).

Comment: @Alf If you have access to pip, you can install things in your home directory with `pip install --user h5py`.

Comment: I just did this a few minutes before you posted it ;) It is working now (with my code above) and the output reads:

Comment: the output reads:         

`(u'DIMENSION_LABELS', array(['m', ''], dtype=object))        
(u'DIMENSION_LIST', array([array([<HDF5 object reference>], dtype=object),
       array([], dtype=object)], dtype=object)) `

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but since the error references `TypeVlenID`, it may have something to do with an incomplete implementation of `vlen` in `h5py` (especially in our version of the module).

[Inexplicable behavior when using vlen with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543791/inexplicable-behavior-when-using-vlen-with-h5py)

[Writing to compound dataset with variable length string via h5py (HDF5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247432/writing-to-compound-dataset-with-variable-length-string-via-h5py-hdf5)

Comment: hmm, thanks for pointing me to that problem, I will read up on that.